# load an svg from server and show it into an html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have tried to load an svg from server and show it into an html element using jQuery like as follows,but it does not show the svg,what is wrong with this code?

I know it can show using `<img>` tag,but i need to write some events on the svg elements.

```js
$.get( "http://example.com/_assets/img/gptest.svg", function( data ) {
   $( "#svg-main" ).append( data );
   });
```

```html
<div id="svg-main"></div>
```

Comment: What does your SVG data look like?

Comment: no need of js. you need use image tag instead. <img src="http://example.com/_assets/img/gptest.svg" />

Comment: did you check console? if the image is from a different domain some browsers like chrome will block the request.(Cross origin requests) .Also use  `  $( "#svg-main" ).append( "<img src='"+data+"'"> ); `

Comment: it brings certain advantages not to use image tag (css works) but inline it.

Comment: what happens if you log the data?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add an `img`-tag?

```
<img src="http://example.com/_assets/img/gptest.svg">
```

If you want to add it via jQuery do it like this:

```
$('#svg-main').append('<img src="http://example.com/_assets/img/gptest.svg">');
```

Comment: As mentioned in question: I know it can show using `<img>` tag,but i need to write some events on the svg elements.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a handy article](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/) about svg.

Basically you need to define width nad height in order ot display svg image.

So that's probably why it is not displaying in your case.